# How to determine what headers are never indexed with HPACK?

Tags: hpack

How does hpack determine what index values are never to be indexed? The rfc has a section ["6.2.3. Literal Header Field Never Indexed"](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7541#section-6.2.3), but I'm confused as to how this is determined.